# working with LDAP authorization hook

Tags: 7, hooks, authentication-authorization

While I have been able to use the LDAP authentication hook 
(`hook_ldap_authentication_allowuser_results_alter`) to perform additional authentication,
I have not been able to use what I thought was the LDAP authorization hook
(`hook_ldap_authorization_maps_alter`, defined in the LDAP authorization module, file *ldap_authorization.api.php*) - the hook never gets executed.

The purpose is to assign user roles to newly created, LDAP-authenticated accounts (therefore I need a Drupal ID). We can't currently use LDAP-Drupal user role mappings because our LDAP does not contain the necessary information to determine the role; instead we need to tap a different database to determine this, and I was hoping that there would a hook somewhere during account creation.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? Also have you looked into hook_user_presave (D7) or hook_user (D6) ?

Comment: I forgot to specify - Drupal 7. I did not know about hook_user_presave(), didn't realize it had changed from Drupal 6. No wonder hook_user() didn't work! 
Thanks, I will definitely try it, since I also need to be able to remove associated user data whenever a LDAP-authenticated user is removed, and needed a hook for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been down this route a few times (looking at using LDAP integration module) each time I ended up writing my own LDAP integration.  Everyone implements differently, I just take the pieces I like from the LDAP module out there (6 or 7) and use your own code to do it.  As a general rule, anytime the rubber hits the road with integrating Drupal with user authentication / authorization systems in an organization I brute force them together via a custom / forked module.  You'll always know your own auth system's specific needs, D.O. will not :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I hope I won't have to go down this path for a while...;)